# Looking for a TCXO with marking R26MOK6

Tags: identification, datasheet, tcxo

I want to use a device (GNSS) for generating a clock signal that has this TCXO on it.
I don't find any useful information with the given marking.
My guess is, that this TCXO has 48MHz.
The reason why i need a datasheet is that i want to know the quality of the signal regarding drift over temperature and time.

As far as i see it the following is printed:

**R26MOK6**

**852**

***r811**

The asterisk (point) is maybe the Pin1 marking.

[image: TCXO]

Comment: Why do you think this is 48 MHz?

Comment: Because i setup the output frequency to 24MHz (maximum). I read in a blog that the internal frequency is at least divided by 2. Unfortunately i dont't have the source anymore

Comment: Looking into it, this looks like a weird oscillator. Standard pinout of these six-pin oscillators puts ground on pin 3 (connected to a plane, that's normal) and output enable on pin 1 (which here is connected to ground--which would permanently disable the oscillator).

Comment: What are the dimensions of the part? There are a couple common sizes for these, and knowing if it's a 5x3.2 mm one or a 3.2x2.5 mm one would help.

Comment: Dimensions: 2.5mm x 2mm